# Can't scroll on touch devices (multiscroll.js)

Tags: scroll, touch, fullpage.js, device, multiscroll.js

I'm using the plugin multiscroll.js and everything works fine but I can't scroll on touch devices.

Any help? Thank you.

```
$('#myContainer').multiscroll({

sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3']

});


function multi() {

if ($(window).width() < 991) {

  $('#myContainer').multiscroll.destroy();


} else {

  $('#myContainer').multiscroll.build();

}
}
multi();  

$(window).resize(function(){

multi(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something wrong, the [demo site](http://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/) works correctly.

And [the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js) say:

> It is designed to work as well on touch devices such as mobile phones or tablets.

It seems that you are destroying it for mobile phones!!

```
if ($(window).width() < 991) {

  $('#myContainer').multiscroll.destroy();
```

Comment: Hello alvaro.Thank you for your response.
If I don't destroy still doesn't work.I modified a little the css to make the content on devices scrollable,I mean normal scroll not the way multiscroll does.If you resize the window of my site you will see.

Comment: If you are having troubles, just use [of the examples provided in multiScroll.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js/tree/master/examples) and start from it. This way you will avoid problems.